# display database in HTML table in separate rows using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

i want to make html page that accept user entries and store it in the database mysql
then another php page to display the data in table

the user will enter name and will choose the months 
the table should display the 12 months with the correspond name

i managed to make it like this

http://s9.postimg.org/po8kh6mz3/image.jpg

but i want the data to be displayed in separate rows not under each others

this is the HTML page look like

http://postimg.org/image/88e4cibqp/

every time the user will enter different name and i want it to display in the table in separate rows.

this is the code for the html page

```
<body>
<section class="container">
<div class="login">
<h1>ARABIAN HOMES</h1>
<form name="myForm" action="conn.php" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<p>Name: <input type="text" name="adname"  /> </p><br />
<h3>2014</h3>

<input name="jan" type="checkbox"/>Jan
<input name="feb" type="checkbox"/>Feb
<input name="mar" type="checkbox"/>Mar
<input name="apr" type="checkbox"/>Apr
<input name="may" type="checkbox"/>May
<input name="jun" type="checkbox"/>Jun
<input name="jul" type="checkbox"/>Jul
<input name="aug" type="checkbox"/>Aug
<input name="sep" type="checkbox"/>Sep
<input name="oct" type="checkbox"/>Oct
<input name="nov" type="checkbox"/>Nov
<input name="decmb" type="checkbox"/>Dec
<div style="text-align:center">  
<input name="" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<input name="" type="button" value="View"  onclick="window.location='view.php'"/>
```

Then i make this page to check if the user check the checkbox or not. 1 means checked 0 is not. and insert it to the database

```
$adname = $_POST['adname'];
if (isset($_POST['jan'])) {
$jan=1;
} else {
$jan=0;
}

if (isset($_POST['feb'])) {
$feb=1;
} else {
$feb=0;
}

if (isset($_POST['mar'])) {
$mar=1;
} else {
$mar=0;
}
.
.//for all montha



$sql= "INSERT INTO ad (name, jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, decmb) VALUES ('$adname','$jan','$feb', '$mar', '$apr', '$may', '$jun', '$jul', '$aug', '$sep', '$oct' ,'$nov' ,'$decmb')
```

and finally page for displaying only name with the checked checkbox in html table

```
$sql1=mysql_query("select name from ad where jan=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql2=mysql_query("select name from ad where feb=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql3=mysql_query("select name from ad where mar=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql4=mysql_query("select name from ad where apr=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql5=mysql_query("select name from ad where may=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql6=mysql_query("select name from ad where jun=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql7=mysql_query("select name from ad where jul=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql8=mysql_query("select name from ad where aug=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql9=mysql_query("select name from ad where sep=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql10=mysql_query("select name from ad where oct=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql11=mysql_query("select name from ad where nov=1") or die(mysql_error());
$sql12=mysql_query("select name from ad where decmb=1") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border=\"3\" width=\"100%\" align=\"center\"><tr><th  height=\"40px\">January</th><th>February</th><th>March</th><th>April</th><th>May</th> <th>June</th><th>July</th><th>August</th><th>September</th><th>October</th> <th>November</th><th>December</th></tr>";

echo "<tr valign=\"top\" align=\"center\"><td>";while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{echo "{$row1['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{echo "{$row2['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";while($row3=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
{echo "{$row3['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";while($row4=mysql_fetch_array($sql4))
{echo "{$row4['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";while($row5=mysql_fetch_array($sql5))
{echo "{$row5['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";while($row6=mysql_fetch_array($sql6))
{echo "{$row6['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";while($row7=mysql_fetch_array($sql7))
{echo "{$row7['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";while($row8=mysql_fetch_array($sql8))
{echo "{$row8['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";while($row9=mysql_fetch_array($sql9))
{echo "{$row9['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";while($row10=mysql_fetch_array($sql10))
{echo "{$row10['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($sql11))
{echo "{$row11['name']}</br>";}
echo "</td>";

    echo "<td>";while($row12=mysql_fetch_array($sql12))
{echo "{$row12['name']}</tr></br>";}
echo "</td>";

echo "</table>";
```

apologize for that and i know i'm not good in this and there is easy way to avoid this long code. but the only help i want it from you that the information is displayed in the table in separate rows for all months

thanks in advance